# Bring up UIActionSheet when tapping and holding an attributed string

Tags: ios

How would I bring up UIActionSheet when tapping and holding an attributed string, not just tapping. This is seen in the official twitter app.

Comment: What is the link held in, web view? Show some code...

Comment: If it's in UIWebView you have to override some of the builtin methods with UIWebViewDelegate... there are a few.

Comment: it is a attributed string

Comment: You can't tap an attributed string. Do you mean you want to do this when a user taps on a label that is displaying an attributed string? Add a long press gesture recognizer to the label.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I needed to do

Answer (score 0):

You have to set UIWebViewDelegate in your header file. THen initiate webivew delegate to self, so you can override the below method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  }
```

From there you can intercept the hyperlink, based on navigation URL type, and initiate your UIActionSheet, which you set as a delegate, and can override.

You can also override gesture recognizers, and detect duration for long vs short taps in the same method. If the threshold exceeds a duration, show the given context uiactionsheet menu.

Keep in mind this is kind of a cloogey way of doing things, you may just want to try to do a web way of using JQuery of JQTouch, with context menus instead of piecing together a native iOS and web js solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the UILongPressGestureRecognizer and set a longPressGestureRecognizer on the label itself. Then I was able to open the action sheet